# Add UI component on form directly in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, uicomponent

I want to add UI component `Vendor/Module/view/base/web/js/modal.js`

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
], function ($, Modal) {
    return Modal.extend({...});
});
```

directly to the customer edit form (`Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/customer_form.xml`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">    

</form>
```

What should I write in `customer_form.xml` in this case?

Comment: As I know, `customer_form.xml` is used for Admin. Are you going to change the Admin customer form?

Comment: Yes, I want to change admin customer form. I want to add modal component to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I have some solution. First off all I need to add new UI component to the page layout:

> .../view/adminhtml/layout/customer_index_edit.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <uiComponent name="vndr_accounts_customer_modal"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

then I should create UI component description:

> .../view/adminhtml/ui_component/vndr_accounts_customer_modal.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<modal xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd"
       name="vndr_accounts_customer_modal"
       template="templates/customer/modal">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module/js/customer/accounting</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <dataSource name="vndr_accounts_customer_modal_ds">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">\Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">vndr_accounts_customer_moda_ds</argument>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
</modal>
```

I need to describe template & data source or I will get an errors on the page.

Template:

> .../view/adminhtml/ui_component/templates/customer/modal.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<div xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_template.xsd">
    <div id="modal_panel_placeholder"></div>
</div>
```

HTML from this template will be placed under "Customer Form" code.

JS code for UI component:

> .../view/adminhtml/web/js/customer/accounting.js

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'uiComponent'
], function ($, Component) {
    var result = Component.extend({
        applyAction: function() {
            alert('Done!');
        }
    });
    return result;
});
```

Add action button to the Customer Form:

> .../view/adminhtml/ui_component/customer_form.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="vndrAccounting" xsi:type="string">Venodr\Module\Block\Customer\Adminhtml\Edit\AccountingButton</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</form>
```

Create button itself:

> .../Block/Customer/Adminhtml/Edit/AccountingButton.php

```
class AccountingButton
    extends \Magento\Customer\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\GenericButton
    implements \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Control\ButtonProviderInterface
{
    public function getButtonData()
    {
        $data = [
            'label' => __('Accounting'),
            'id' => 'customer-edit-vndr-accounting',
            'on_click' => "require('uiRegistry').get('vndr_accounts_customer_modal.vndr_accounts_customer_modal').applyAction()"
                ];
        return $data;
    }
}
```

I use uiRegistry 'God Object' on the front to get my ui-component and to fire action.

```
require('uiRegistry').get('vndr_accounts_customer_modal.vndr_accounts_customer_modal').applyAction()
```

Please, get me know if you have a shorter way to achieve the same result.